# BigQuery main to intraday table transfer question

Tags: sql, database, select, google-bigquery, transfer

Im new in BigQuery db system and know that there is some mechanism when daily collected data is transfered from table_intraday_ to table_. I have working sql script that grab data from parquet files generated by BQ scheduled query which in its turn runs on daily basis to export data for last day. I have specific time to run this query and sometimes it fails because there is no data for last day in _intraday because it already came to main table. Is there any way to prognose time when data comes from _intraday to main table ? I have idea to write dynamic BQ sql scripts that will check existence of both _intraday and main table data for last day and pull data from existing one. Can be there problem that data exists in both tables _intraday and main and I need to wait until transfering complete ?

Comment: Can you provide more details of your issue and how you are collecting data also confirming if you are using firebase or not ?

Comment: Once a day I pulling data from intraday table with specific date , for example events_intraday_23112023 
I know that events_intraday_ keep only current day and at the start of next day (which we can't control , it is handled by Google Cloud ) this data will be moved to events_.  Collecting of data consists of export command to Google CLoud Storage parquets and SQL command that grab that data into Clickhouse. Sometimes during parquet export I get error that there is no table  found events_intraday_23112023 , and I see that this data already in events_23112023 .